# cvt is acting strange when defining resoluton

Tags: xorg

I am trying to define a new currently unsupported resolution on a virtual machine (Linux Deepin client) with a 1366×768 screen. So I first try to use command `cvt`:

```
cvt 1366 768 60
```

and it returns:

```
# 1368x768 59.88 Hz (CVT) hsync: 47.79 kHz; pclk: 85.25 MHz
Modeline "1368x768_60.00"   85.25  1368 1440 1576 1784  768 771 781 798 -hsync +vsync
```

which is incorrect as it changed the `1366` to `1368`! Why is this happening? I need this output to use it with X. So I am stuck!

Answer (score 1):

The generated modeline is correct according to the standard: [CVT](https://glenwing.github.io/docs/VESA-CVT-1.2.pdf) requires that horizontal counts are a multiple of 8:

> All definitions referring to the horizontal timing, including the horizontal active pixels, horizontal total pixels, sync pulse duration and “Front porch” and “Back Porch” times, must be divisible by
>   eight, and preferably by higher powers of two.

1366 isn’t divisible by 8, so `cvt` rounds up to the next integer which is, 1368. The generated modeline *should* work fine with your screen. If it doesn’t, and you’re using a digital output (DVI, HDMI, or DP), you can try adjusting it directly:

```
Modeline "1366x768_60.00"   85.25  1366 1440 1576 1784  768 771 781 798 -hsync +vsync
```

(The dotclock is slightly off, this ends up being something like 60.03Hz, but that shouldn’t matter.)

Comment: Well the demand for a multiple of 8 is a nonsense if you ask me. Is this a legacy of X server? Will Wayland fix this? How is it possible that on some Linux distributions I can turn on 1366x768? Did they trick me and I was actually using 1368x768 all the time?

Comment: This has nothing to do with X or Wayland, it’s required by the VESA CVT standard (see the link in my answer). You might be able to fudge it if necessary, see my update. Most systems connected to a real 1366×768 display will use that resolution natively *via* KMS, so that would explain why it works on other distributions.

Comment: I take it you’ve tried 1368×768 too, and that doesn’t work either?

Comment: I tried adding `video=Virtual-0:1366x768@60` (I checked that Virtual-0 is right connector) to my kernel parameters at boot time and no support for 1366x768 resolution was presented. I still have no clue on how to get this resolution. It was said that I could add any resolution via KMS.

Comment: I tried it after you suggested and `video=Virtual-0:1368x768@60` doesn't work either.